# Loading html file using js in django project

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a django template in which I want to load a html file in a div depending on the value of a select box.
This is the target div:

```
<table id="template" class="table">
     Where to load tables.
</table>
```

I have an  tag:
`<a href="#" onclick='loadHtml("template", "user_table.html")'>dadjias</a>`

Which when clicked calls the javascript function:

```
function loadHtml(id, filename) {
      let xhttp;
      let element = document.getElementById(id);
      let file = filename;

      if (file) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {element.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
            if (this.status == 404) {element.innerHTML = "<h1> Page not found.</h1>";}
          }
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", `templates/${file}`, true);
        xhttp.send();
        return;
      }
    }
```

However the issue is that for some reason when the function is called, the file cannot be found so the 'Page not found' displays on screen.

These are the files in my django project:

Files in Django project

[image: 1]

The html file I am tring to load in the div is at the bottom.

Comment: You would need to serve them from the static file system, no?

Comment: You may be interested in HTMX. See example here https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/ but it doesn't have to be another select as the target, it can be your div.

Comment: although generated ai content is temporarily banned, a prompt like "Can you provide an example of using Django and htmx to dynamically update a div based on the selection of an item in a dropdown list? Please include example code for the views.py, urls.py, and template files." using chatGPT provides a decent example on how to use htmx for this task. My first time suggesting such a thing and feels like the early days of "Google It" so apologies if it comes across like that, not my intent - exploring how the current tools can assist.

Answer (score 0):

Update this line of code `xhttp.open("GET", 'templates/${file}', true);` with this `xhttp.open("GET", "templates/" + file, true);`

So the code script will look like this:

```
function loadHtml(id, filename) {
      let xhttp;
      let element = document.getElementById(id);
      let file = filename;

      if (file) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if (this.status == 200) {element.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
            if (this.status == 404) {element.innerHTML = "<h1> Page not found.</h1>";}
          }
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "templates/" + file, true);
        xhttp.send();
        return;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I get a TemplateSyntaxError, expected endblock

Comment: at which line of the code?

Comment: I have updated my answer can you try this and test if it works?

Comment: It compiles but I still get page not found in the div so the html file is not able to be found

Comment: Try your templates/ folder file to access directly from browser URL and see if that's work.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, could you explain?